# Simple Custom Pallet making XCM call

Tags: xcm, substrate-node

Are there any `pallet` examples for custom making `XCM` call. I know there is ping pallet provided by cumulus but I believe that is pretty old.

Does ping pallet still works?

Answer (score 0):

There are numeric examples in this pallet. You can check them at the following link: [GitHub - Open Web3 Stack - XTokens README](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/master/xtokens/README.md).

For example, you can construct an XCM using the code snippet provided here: [GitHub - Open Web3 Stack - XTokens lib.rs](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/28a2e6f0df9540d91db4018c7ecebb8bfc217a2a/xtokens/src/lib.rs#L687-L694).